# Not able to click the Inline element using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB2V6.jpg)Not able to click the inline element using selenium webdriver.

Here is the URL
[`https://www.google.com/.`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB2V6.jpg)

Besides Images link (Right side top) there is a square icon. Need to click that icon and select Maps.
Screenshot attached.
I used xpath, cssselector, ID, Name but nothing is working. 
Could anyone help me on this.

Code:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class webelements2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\rpremala003\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.id("gbwa")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.className("gb_3")).click();               
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is somehow not working in Firefox because it opens the Products page when you click on element - `By.id("gbwa")`. But if you try the same in Chrome, it works fine. Only thing you would need to change is `By.className("gb_3")` with `By.xpath("//ul[@class='gb_ka gb_da']/li[3]")`.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.id("gbwa")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='gb_ka gb_da']/li[3]")).click();
```

For Firefox, you can modify the code so that when the products page is opened, you can click on the Maps option from there.

Comment: Hi Anish, thanks for the reply. Again page is navigating to products page only. It's not clicking the maps icon.

Answer (score 0):

Some dynamic waits need to be added for controls. Additionally, I noticed that, if google is not set as your home page then you see a message 'Come here often? Make Google your homepage.'. This message needs to be handled, otherwise it will fail the access to the apps icon.

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
public class webelements2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\rpremala003\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@title='No thanks']")).size() !=0) {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='No thanks']"))));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='No thanks']")).click();
        }

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gb']//div[@id='gbwa']/div/a[@title='Google apps' and @role='button']")).click();

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='gb8']/span[text()='Maps']"))));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='gb8']/span[text()='Maps']")).click();               
    }       
}
```

Try this code and let me know, if you have further queries.

Comment: Thanks Mahi. Google was set to default in my firefox browser. When I used ur code it's asking to initialize the WAIT.

Comment: **wait** has been initialized in the code. Did you add the required import statements?

Comment: The code was working for me. May be we need to check that all the dependencies have been resolved.

Comment: I got this issue "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method until(Function) from the type Wait"

Comment: All alphabets in **wait** should be in lowercase i.e. use **wait** instead of **Wait**. Let me know, if you face in further issue.

Comment: if I make them small letters then following error is getting displayed.  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method until(Function) from the type Wait

Comment: Could you share your full class code(including import statements)? As, I am not getting this error at my end.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the code below and it works.

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='Google apps']")).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("gb8"))).click();
```

You basically need to click the Apps icon, wait for the Maps icon to be clickable, and click it.

I'm assuming you don't work for Google so in that case, why test the UI? You can just directly navigate to https://maps.google.com and skip the UI clicks.

Comment: Hey Jeff, thanks for the reply. Again page is navigating to products page only. It's not clicking the maps icon.

Comment: In your question, it states, "Besides Images link (Right side top) there is a square icon. Need to click that icon and select Maps." What does that mean if it doesn't mean to click the Maps icon?

Answer (score 0):

How about this ... worked for me.

```
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gbwa']//a[@title='Google apps']"))));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gbwa']//a[@title='Google apps']")).click();

    //click map icon
    driver.findElement(By.cssselector("a#gb8")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, working for me.

Use Chrome driver instead of Firefox driver.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class GoogleMaps {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gbwa']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/a[@id='gb8']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Output :

[image]